# In TALEND, loop through dynamically deep recursive XML elements

Tags: xml, talend, recursive-datastructures

I have an XML document I'm trying to process using Talend, and I have everything else working, but I realized that I was only handling the surface level elements.

The data I'm working with is the XML task data generated by the program **Taskcoach version 1.4.3**, and I need to look at some of the tasks of a certain category, the sorting of which I've managed, and all of the subtasks of those tasks, and the subtasks of them ad infinitum.

Subtasks in Taskcoach are task elements just like the ones they're contained in, the only difference being that they're stored a level lower. I say ad infinitum because I don't want to break the program by creating a subtask one level deeper than the Talend job can handle.

I am very new to Talend, so I sure I'm just missing something, but none of the resources I've found have been clear on how this can work. I found [this documentation](http://doc.talend.com/enterprise/talend_data_mapper/3.3/map_iter.php) but have no idea what it's talking about, and I've found nothing about recursive XML in The Talend Cookbook, hitherto my primary source on Talend.